# Page Split caused by update to Binary(128) Column

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sqldatatypes, fillfactor

I have a table with a Binary(128) column. I chose Binary(128) over Varbinary(128) so it would reserve all 128 bytes and prevent page splits when updating the binary value. For testing purposes I have a FILLFACTOR of 100 on my index.

I found that even with the column set to a Binary(128) value it would still cause page splits when performing updates to this column.

Anyone have any idea why?

Here is some code to test with...

```
--      Create working dataset
Create  Table   TestTable (tID Int Identity, TestBinary Binary(128));
Create  Clustered Index hmmmm On TestTable (TestBinary) With (FillFactor=100);

With    recur As
(   
        Select  Convert(Binary(128),0x01) As val, 1 As incr
        Union   All
        Select  Convert(Binary(128),incr + 0x01), incr + 1
        From    recur
        Where   incr < 100
)
Insert  TestTable (TestBinary)
Select  Convert(Binary(128),Convert(Int,r.val) + Convert(Int,r2.val) + Convert(Int,r3.val)) As TestBinary
From    recur r
Cross   Join    recur r2
Cross   Join    recur r3;

--      Rebuild Index as needed while testing
Alter   Index [hmmmm] On [dbo].[TestTable] Rebuild

--      Check index fragmentation
SELECT  Db_Name() As DatabaseName,
        o.id,
        s.name, 
        o.name, 
        page_count,
        record_count,
        index_type_desc,
        index_id,
        index_depth,
        index_level,
        avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
        fragment_count,
        avg_fragment_size_in_pages,
        avg_page_space_used_in_percent
From    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), Object_ID('dbo.TestTable'), NULL , NULL, 'Detailed') n
Join    sysobjects o
        On  n.object_id = o.id
Join    sys.schemas s
        On  o.uid = s.schema_id;

--      Update the records
Update  t
Set     TestBinary = Convert(Binary(128),(Convert(Int,TestBinary) + 10000))
From    TestTable t
```

If you perform a large update with the FILLFACTOR at 100 it causes severe fragmentation, but if I have the FILLFACTOR at 90 everything is good. I thought the non-var datatypes were supposed to reserve memory so you don't run into this issue. Where is the storage inflation coming from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be inflation, but rather moving. As you've made a clustered index on your binary(128) column, the data will be sorted according to the value.

As you update the value, the physical record may have to be stored on another page, to maintain the order. If that other page is full, it will have to be split.

Comment: Upvoting because that is a good call and absolutely true. I removed the "Where tID % 10 = 0" from the update and instead updated all the records. This should maintain the order, correct? This still causes fragmentation.

Comment: In the end, yes, it will maintain order. However, while it is a batch operation, each record will eventually have to be updated one-by-one at the physical level. After each record has been updated, it will be moved to the correct location. Thus, the very first record will have to split a page. The next one will probably go to the newly split page, but eventually you'll hit another full page and end up with another page split.

Comment: Last clarifying question before I accept the answer. If I did not have the identity column and instead had a Varchar as the primary key/clustered index, could the changing of the Binary(128) records cause a change to the clustered index that could cause page splits? Would the changing of the included table data associated with the clustered index cause this or since they are all Binary(128) values should the new data perfectly replace the old data?

Comment: Whether you replace the ID column with a varchar, or simply make the ID column the only column in the cluster key, the result would be the same. Any changes to columns not part of the clustered key won't affect the physical location. Thus, changing the Binary(128) column won't affect the clustered key in any way or form, and would thereby ensure you don't fragment your clustered index.

Comment: Hmmm, this is not what I'm seeing, my primary key is based on a varchar(40), the other two columns are binary(128) and datetime column. There are some defaults on the binary(128) and datetime and the varchar(40) has a foreign key reference to another table, but I don't think that stuff should make any difference. I'll take till tomorrow to see if I can recreate the issue I'm experiencing in test data I can provide and if I can't I'll accept your answer because it seems right and I must just be missing something in production.

Comment: If you have a (clustered!) primary key consisting of just a varchar(40) field and you only update the binary(128) and datetime fields, it should, under no circumstances, result in fragmentation - unless you happen to be using the compression features of SQL Server (in which case it most certainly may cause fragmentation). If you can provide a sample or further details, I'll gladly have a look at it. Also - I assume that foreign key doesn't have a cascading update, resulting in it being updated as a side effect of whatever else you're doing?

Comment: I can't figure it out, in the product table it causes page splits, but if I create a new table and copy the data over it doesn't. I think it must be related to the fact that the table originally had a Varbinary(128) and I altered the table to a Binary(128). It looks like all the values got updated to Binary(128) values with the trailing zeroes, but maybe there is some behind the scenes something causing it. (No compression) I'll try recreating the table from scratch and see what happens. Thanks for the help.